# Cannot use IOVA as PA in running pipeline application using DPDK

Tags: dpdk

I am using DPDK 19.11 in Linux Ubuntu 18 vm. I am able to run PDUMP and testpmd sample applications successfully.

To execute IP pipeline application, I assigned four ports to DPDK and loaded KNI interface as well. I have used sample firewall.cli configuration from DPDK examples folder. I updated ports address in firewall.cli

When I start the pipeline application, the following error gets displayed.
EAL:FATAL Cannot use IOVA as PA since  physical addresses are not available.

EAL initialization failed.

Can you please help how to overcome this error and share some more firewall.cli examples.

Comment: Executed with root user account and error didn't come

Comment: expected behaviour as `sudo` gives Physical Address access

Comment: there is always an option to run without sudo privilege too. but current question is not about running without sudo

Answer (score 3):

As per the update shared in comments the cause of error is not having right privellege to access the Physical Address of Huge page

Logs:

```
EAL:FATAL Cannot use IOVA as PA since physical addresses are not available.
EAL initialization failed.
```

Solution is to run with `sudo` or execute from user with super user priveleges.